# Cannot get past permission denied after setting user, group and permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions, httpd.conf

I'm using a php library to access noaa content https://github.com/amwhalen/noaa

When running a command that includes caching of results I'm getting the following

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/forecast_6ec13dc4d307f55854f7617f9debc515.xml):
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/******/Documents/www/noaa-master/noaa/weather/cache/FileCache.php on line 51
```

OS is OSX Yosemite.

I have checked ownership of the files and permissions.... Here is what I have...

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 _www  _www  2543 Mar 26 10:50 FileCache.php
```

As for what user is running Apache via (ps aux | grep httpd)

```
_www              446   0.0  0.0  2476992    936   ??  S    12:04PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

_www is also the user and group declared in httpd.conf which makes sense considering the above.

My root set in apache is:

```
/Users/******/Documents/www
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the directories writeable too?

Comment: Here is the ls -ll for the directory the file is in  drwxrwxrwx  6 _www  _www  204 Mar 26 10:50 cache

Comment: What do the Apache error logs tell you?

Comment: Access log shows the url request and nothing else, error log shows nothing after stating apache  `[Thu Mar 26 12:37:24.433529 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 555] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8zc configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 26 12:37:24.433558 2015] [core:notice] [pid 555] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'`

Comment: So, you're trying to write to the file `/forecast_6ec13dc4d307f55854f7617f9debc515.xml` ? Is that getting called correctly with the preceding slash?

Comment: I'm assuming it is, this is a widely used API and no one else seems to be having issues with it.  I could go start dismantling the code but my guess is it's an issue on my end, also if that was the issue I don't think I'd be getting the error I am, do you?

Comment: Does that look at server root for the file *forecast_...*?

Comment: It does indeed. looks like it is the API afterall.  If you want to put it as an answer I will mark as solved.